# How to do speech to text with microsoft cognition API?

Tags: node.js, api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I have this node.js code to upload a `wav` file to to speech to text. But it does not work.

I got back this

```
{"RecognitionStatus":"InitialSilenceTimeout","Offset":58100000,"Duration":0}
```

code

```
var data = fse.readFileSync("assets/batman.wav");
data = data.toString();

var options = {
    host : 'speech.platform.bing.com',
    //port : 443,
    path : '/speech/recognition/dictation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=simple',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : 'my key',
        'Content-type' : 'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000'
    }
};
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    var buffer = "";
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        var str = buffer.toString();
        console.log("A", buffer);
        //var json = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
        //console.log(json);
    });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request:', e.message);
});
// add data
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [cognitive services REST API example page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedrest) the data needs to be sent as raw bytes (i.e. no toString).